# why cannot call function in button? Phaser

Tags: function, timer, intervals, phaser-framework

I cannot use the start function, what can I do guys? What is my problem? I hope everyone helps me :) .Thanks you for helping in advance !

```
var diff,
        increase_end_angle = 0,
        start_angle = 1.5 * Math.PI,end_angle = 2 * Math.PI,
        startTime = (new Date()).getTime(),
        circleTimer;

    create: function {
        button =  this.game.add.button(0,0,'btnNext', this.start,this);
    },

    circleTimer: function () {
                var graphics = game.add.graphics(0, 0);         
                diff = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
                diff = diff / 60000; //60000ms = 60s            
                increase_end_angle = start_angle + end_angle * diff + reduce;                     
                graphics = game.add.bitmapData(80,80);
                graphics.context.fillStyle = '#D24545';
                graphics.context.beginPath();             
                graphics.context.arc(x,y,radius,start_angle,increase_end_angle,false);
                graphics.context.lineTo(x,y);
                graphics.context.fill();       
                graphics.context.closePath();
                game.add.image(13, 8, graphics);
    },

    start: function () {
        circleTimer = setInterval(this.circleTimer, 200);
    },

    update: function() {
       if(diff > 1 ) {
            clearInterval(circleTimer);
       }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working just fine for me: http://codepen.io/kozulowski/pen/dPjXvY.

You seem to be missing some variables: I can't see a declaration for `reduce`, `radius`, `x`, `y` etc.

Comment: everything is working, I have a button in order to start the game, so I pass the function circleTimer to start function then when I press the button it will start the game. My problem is that when I click the button, it wont start the setInterval(this.circleTimer, 200) function. Any idea bro?

Comment: Check the pen again, the circleTimer function gets called, but there are a lof of errrors due to missing variables - check the javascript console.